# Derived category of certain ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm interested in the structure of $D^b(R)$, where $R=k[x]/(x^n)$. How one can describe this category? What is the list of indecomposable objects in this category?

Comment: Can you do the case $n=2$?

Comment: Yes. It is the only case that I understand.

Comment: I would start as follows. What is a module over $k[x]/x^n$? First, it is a module over $k$, so it is a vectorspace $V$. Furthermore $V$ is equipped with a matrix $M$ so that $M^n=0$. If $k$ is algebraically closed you can find the possible Jordan normal forms of the matrices $M$.

Comment: I *think* "indecomposable" was meant. Please revert me if I'm wrong. In any case "idecompossible" is basically a googlewhack.

Comment: If you are interested in the list of indecomposable objects, then you might as well be interested in the Auslander-Reiten theory of $D^b(R)$, in which case, some results are known.  (Very roughly, AR-theory is about triangles of indecomposable objects)  I am no expert in this, but I think one can start to have a look at Sarah Scherotzke's results (all on arXiv), which rely on a result of Wheeler (that I don't understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no wonder you can only do the case $n\leq 2$. In fact these are the only cases where it is possible to give a list of all the indecomposable objects. This is described by the notion of derived wildness, see the paper [Derived tame local and two-point algebras](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869309003007) by Bekkert, Drozd and Futorny.

As was remarked already in the comments by Aaron, one can ask other "classification questions" like: How does the (stable) Auslander-Reiten quiver look like. This was answered by Wheeler in [The triangulated structure of the stable derived category](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869384710969#) The non-trivial Auslander-Reiten components for self-injective algebras all look like $\mathbb{Z}[A_\infty]$.